# Select/ Extract rows basis of rowname in R

Tags: r

I want to extract some rows from my data in R based on specific identifier in column `ids`. My data is like this:

```
ids         A1     B1     C1    D1    E1 ...
asd.wd.01   12     23     27    32    76
qsd.yh.02   54     32     32    11    22
gsd.kj.01   22     21     67    88    22 
hnd.gd.02   22     88     42    41    93
sjd.td.01   52     31     72    19    31
```

And I want following output:  (row with `01` eg. `xxx.xx.01`)

```
ids         A1     B1     C1    D1    E1 ...
asd.wd.01   12     23     27    32    76
gsd.kj.01   22     21     67    88    22 
sjd.td.01   52     31     72    19    31
```

Comment: perhaps `df[grepl("01",df$ids),]` ?

Comment: you can use `grep` as well, and try with `"01$"` to specify that the pattern needs to be at the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

You can use string matching. For example

```
Index <- grep("\\.01$", df$ids) ## Gives index of rows which contains .01
df <- df[Index, ]  ## subsets dataframe
```

Comment: Yeah i will edit the answer thanks

Comment: @mona if your `ids` are actually rownames, juste replace `df$ids` by `row.names(df)` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract rows by using grepl

```
df <- subset(df, grepl("\\.01$", df$ids)
```

Comment: Thanks all, Sorry I forgot to mentioned that my first column is without header (no "ids")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         A1     B1     C1    D1    E1 ...
asd.wd.01   12     23     27    32    76
qsd.yh.02   54     32     32    11    22
gsd.kj.01   22     21     67    88    22 
hnd.gd.02   22     88     42    41    93
sjd.td.01   52     31     72    19    31

Answer (score -1):

Use `%>%` (Pipe Operator) and `filter()` from `dplyr` package and `%like%` from `data.table` package. Extracted rows where `Name` ends with `.1`. You can use your data and do the similar substitution.

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(data.table)
> df <- data.frame(Name=c("A.1","B.1","A.3","B.2","C.1"),A=1:5,B=5:9,C=10:14)
> df
  Name A B  C
1  A.1 1 5 10
2  B.1 2 6 11
3  A.3 3 7 12
4  B.2 4 8 13
5  C.1 5 9 14

> df %>% filter(Name %like% ".1")
  Name A B  C
1  A.1 1 5 10
2  B.1 2 6 11
3  C.1 5 9 14
```